# Django: null value in column "shipping_address_owner_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to add new record to my invoice model table but i keep getting the **error** message

> **IntegrityError**
> null value in column "shipping_address_owner_id" violates not-null constraint

My guess is the column `shipping_address_owner` which is using **ForeignKey** that links it to a second table called `ShippingAddress`.

I'm trying to add the following entry to my `paymentInvoice` model table but i'm getting the above stated error

```
{
    "shipping_address_owner": "Becky",
    "product": [
        "Sepit"
    ],    
    "quantity": 1,
    "payment_made": "2600.00"
}
```

Below is my **paymentInvoice** model table

```
class paymentInvoice(models.Model):

    shipping_address_owner = models.ForeignKey(ShippingAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_invoice")
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='product_invoice')
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    invoice_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=increment_invoice_number)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    payment_made = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shipping_address_owner.customer.name
```

My **ShippingAddress** model

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_ship_address")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.name
```

My **serializer** file

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    shipping_address_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = '__all__'

   def get_shipping_address_owner(self, instance):
        return instance.shipping_address_owner.customer.name

    def get_product(self, instance):
        names = []
        for product in instance.product.all(): # get all products field
            names.append(product.name) # append the product name
        return names
```

Comment: The error is telling you that when you're submitting your object to your model it is receiving a `null` value for `shipping_address_owner_id`. By default Django doesn't accept null values to the database, you have to specify this by doing something like `shipping_address_owner_id = models.CharField(null=True)`. What's strange is I can't see a field for `shipping_address_owner_id` in your model? Did you have it there before and delete it? If so you may not have made the appropriate migrations.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but I figured that would be a double entry in that ``shipping_address_owner`` is already a **ForeignKey**  linking the Invoice table to shipping table.

Comment: So did you delete the `shipping_address_owner_id` from your model? If so did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after?

Comment: I didn't have ``shipping_address_owner_id``

Comment: After adding and making the migration i got an error ``ERRORS:
customers.paymentInvoice.shipping_address_owner: (models.E006) The field 'shipping_address_owner' clashes with the field 'shipping_address_owner_id' from model 'customers.paymentinvoice'.``

Comment: For some reason your database has a column `shipping_address_owner_id` that is expecting a value when you're submitting objects to your model. In your `ShippingAddress` model the field `Customer` is a ForeignKey to the model `Customer`, the error may lie in a field you have there. If not, this thread may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590231/how-can-i-solve-an-integrity-error-for-a-field-that-doesnt-exist